# SAS Assign Role or Group to User

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide, sas-metadata

I have a user account, but i need a script for assign a role or group to my user, is this possible from Enterprise Guide?

PDT: The role and the group was created previously.

Answer (score 1):

It is **possible**, but would involve using the User Import Macros. These require quite a bit of reading to get your head around. It isn't as simple as having a nice procedure to do the job.

[SAS User Import Macros](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/bisecag/69827/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1ar98lajfgm4jn1wa1h6e19jjre.htm)